# block php file access (modsecurity)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

How can I block all access to a PHP file?  File name is similar to `sm6######.php` where `####` can be any random digit.

How can I do it using `mod_sec`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SecRule REQUEST_LINE "@rx sm6[0-9]{1,}\.php" \
"phase:2,block,severity:2,msg:'Blocking access to sm6#.php files.'"
```

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a suitable situation for the [`<FilesMatch >` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch), no need for `mod_security` at all.

```
<FilesMatch sm6[0-9]+\.php>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Of course, if you don't want *anyone* to access the file, why not delete it or move it out of the `DocumentRoot` ?

If you edit your question to include more about *who* shouldn't be able to access the file I'll update my answer to match.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This is really very good alternative solution. but problem is that I am bound to use mod security and i can't go away from it.... :( so right now i need to know that how can i achieve my goal using mod security. also please can you tell me precisely that what is main purpose of mod security ... i read that it is used to control access to files. can you please elaborate it ... and tell me how block all access to a file like
 sm6######.php (the #'s can be random numbers, not letters), how would I do it?
 Your help is really appreciated. Thanks again sir.

Comment: You don't know what the purpose of mod_security is but you are bound to use it over a very simple solution for your problem?  If you are not familiar with mod_security, you should not be responsible for administrating rule sets for it.  If you are, you have bigger issues and need to make yourself very familiar with it before moving forward.

Comment: I agree with you sir. but I think this is a way of learning. of course when we start something we don't know about it and thats why we try to learn it. so there is no harm to that i think. ( it doesn't mean i know nothing about it but jst wanted to make myself clear that whatever i am thinking is not worng)

Now the reason, why i m looking for so complicated solution is, that I have to use mod secuirty further for some other tasks and thats why i m starting with a simple task.how can i do something difficult with mod_sec when i can't handle a simple thing with it? hope you understand my point.

Comment: http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/ would be a better place to start.  The basic documentation provides examples which would provide a solution to your question, and more importantly, teach you what mod_security actually is.